# CSS resizable div with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to draw a `<svg>` with a fixed aspect ratio inside a resizable `<div>` that fits to the size of the contained SVG — I want a resizable SVG with a fixed aspect ratio. I can't set the `svg` itself `resize: both`, for some reason, I need to wrap it in a `div`.

I am using the Rust Seed library, so my code is not JavaScript, but you should still get the idea:

```rust
div![ // wrapping div
    style!{
        St::MaxWidth => "100%";
        St::MaxHeight => "100%";
        St::Resize => "both";
        St::Overflow => "auto";
    },
    svg![ // contained svg
        style!{
            St::BackgroundColor => "gray";
        },
        attrs!{
            At::Width => "100%",
            At::Height => "100%",
            At::ViewBox => format!("0 0 {} {}", width, height),
            At::PreserveAspectRatio => "xMinYMin meet",
        },
        text![ // svg text
            "Example SVG"
        ],
    ]
]
```

I can not get the wrapper to match the svg size, I have tried using "min-content", "max-content" on the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` attributes, but it doesn't have the desired effect. How can I get this to work?

This is the current behavior:
[image]

Comment: Your SVG is generated on-the-fly, or it is a static image (so can be served as normal URI to the server)?

Comment: @Anton It's generated on the fly, on the client side.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for? Do you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the svg or do you want it to fill its container no matter what? The former is what you seem to have. In the latter case you should use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

Comment: @AndreNuechter well, I want both. I want the container to stop resizing when it would differ from the SVGs size. Basically I want the same aspect ratio on the container.

Comment: Why is this question being voted to close?

Answer (score 2):

One "solution" is to use `resize: horizontal` and `height: auto` on the container. Also this requires the `height` attribute on the `svg` to be omitted (`width` is also not needed).

```rust
div![
    style!{
        St::Resize => "horizontal",
        St::Overflow => "auto",
        St::Height => "auto",
    },
    svg![
        attrs!{
            At::ViewBox => format!("0 0 {} {}", width, height),
            At::PreserveAspectRatio => "xMinYMin meet",
        },
        text![
            "Example SVG"
        ],
    ]
]
```

Unfortunately this changes the cursor to be `e-resize`, which is not exactly beneficial for user-experience. There are other hacks to change the cursor back, but none which I have tried worked so far.

[image]